# Reload Spring application context after every test

Tags: java, spring, junit

I have a test Class which contains 2 test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:applicationContextTest.xml" })
@Transactional
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = true)

public class MyITest extends implements BeanFactoryAware {

    private BeanFactory beanFactory;

    @Test
    public void test1() throws Exception {}

    @Test
    public void test2() throws Exception {}        
}
```

When I run tests individually I get no errors, but when I run all tests together there is a failure. This failure is due to some tests modifying the application context:

```
  b = beanFactory.getBean("logDataSource", BasicDataSource.class);
  b.set ...
```

Is there an option to run this test separately? I just want when test1 start it read all necessary things then run test and then close all necessary things. And then start test2.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You can use the @DirtiesContext annotation on the test class that modifies the application context.

[Java Doc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/annotation/DirtiesContext.html)

[Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#integration-testing-annotations-spring)

By default, this will mark the application context as dirty after the entire test class is run. If you would like to mark the context as dirty after a single test method, then you can either annotate the test method instead or set the classMode property to AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD at your class level annotation.

```
@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
```

Comment: nice works like a charm thx a lot. There is just one limitation. When I use annotation @Transactional there is still something dirty :)

Comment: Glad it worked out. You might want to try the @Rollback annotation on the test method causing you the trouble. It might be a better idea to just split the test up into 2 clases so it doesn't cause the other test to fail.

Comment: @groodt superb! thanks a lot. Not only did the solution work, but you added an even more sensible solution regarding splitting tests. Btw, I annotated my offending test class with the above and the result, expectedly was a much slower test, but of course, one that works. My specific case: I was using a Spy on a bean that I needed to reset from test to test.

Comment: btw, I removed the class level annotation and added the @DirtiesContext to the offending method, and the test run performance is back to normal.