# Clear Spring application context after test

Tags: spring, junit, spring-test, applicationcontext, junit5

How can I clear the application context after each test execution, with Junit5 and Spring Boot? I want all beans created in the test to be destroyed after its execution, since I am creating the same beans in multiple tests. I don't want to have one configuration class for all tests, but configuration class per test, as shown bellow.

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MyTest.ContextConfiguration.class)
public class MyTest{
   ...
   public static class ContextConfiguration {
     // beans defined here... 

   }
}
```

Putting `@DirtiesContext(classMode = BEFORE_CLASS)` doesn't work with Junit5.

Comment: did you try `@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)`

Comment: It doesn't work. @pvpkiran

Comment: try this solution [Dirties Context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14718088/how-do-you-reset-spring-junit-application-context-after-a-test-class-dirties-it)

Comment: Why? The beans should be singletons and shouldn't keep state. The singleton nature is per application context (i.e. per combination of `classes` loaded with the `@ContextConfiguration`). Trying to recreate them each time will slow down your tests (Spring will cache the context between tests and when the same one comes around re-use it).

Comment: For starters, your `MyTest.ContextConfiguration` class must be annotated with `@Configuration` for it to be considered a configuration class containing `@Bean` methods.

Comment: But I also have to agree with M. Deinum: why do you want to destroy the entire `ApplicationContext` after **every** test method?

Comment: Guys Dirties Context is not working for me too. Can someone help here?

Answer (score 7):

You have claimed twice that `@DirtiesContext(classMode = AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)` does not work; however, the following shows that it works as documented.

```
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestInfo;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.test.annotation.DirtiesContext;
import org.springframework.test.annotation.DirtiesContext.ClassMode;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration
@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
class MyTest {

    @Test
    void test1(TestInfo testInfo) {
        System.err.println(testInfo.getDisplayName());
    }

    @Test
    void test2(TestInfo testInfo) {
        System.err.println(testInfo.getDisplayName());
    }

    @Configuration
    static class Config {

        @Bean
        MyComponent myComponent() {
            return new MyComponent();
        }
    }

}

class MyComponent {

    @PreDestroy
    void destroy() {
        System.err.println("Destroying " + this);
    }
}
```

Executing the above test class results in output to *STDERR* similar to the following.

```
test1(TestInfo)
Destroying MyComponent@dc9876b
test2(TestInfo)
Destroying MyComponent@30b6ffe0
```

Thus, `@DirtiesContext(classMode = AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)` is indeed how you "clear the application context after each test execution".

> Putting `@DirtiesContext(classMode = BEFORE_CLASS)` doesn't work with Junit5.

Based on my testing, `classMode = BEFORE_CLASS` works with TestNG, JUnit 4, and JUnit Jupiter (a.k.a., JUnit 5).

So, if that does not work in your test class, that would be a bug which you should [report to the Spring Team](https://jira.spring.io/secure/CreateIssue!default.jspa).

Do you have any example where you can demonstrate that not working?

FYI: using `classMode = BEFORE_CLASS` would only ever make sense if the context had already been created within the currently executing test suite. Otherwise, you are instructing Spring to close and remove an `ApplicationContext` from the cache that does not exist... just before Spring actually creates it.

Regards,

Sam (*author of the Spring TestContext Framework*)

Comment: The problem is with @Nested classes.

Comment: @RhuanKarlus, I recommend you ask a separate _question_ on Stack Overflow explaining what's not working with `@Nested` test classes.

Comment: See [@DirtiesContext does not work with @Nested tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62142428/dirtiescontext-does-not-work-with-nested-tests)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/annotation/DirtiesContext.html), try `@DirtiesContext(classMode = AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)`

Comment: what is your Spring's version?