# @DirtiesContext does not work with @Nested tests

Tags: spring-boot, integration-testing, junit5

After hours of research on Google I still can't figure out how to use `@DirtiesContext` with `@Nested`classes. Assuming the following Integration Test class :

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(addFilters = false)
public class StuffIntegrationTests {

    @Autowired
    private StuffRepository stuffRepository;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    private MockMvc mvc;

    // ...

    @BeforeEach
       private void setUp() {
       mvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .webAppContextSetup(context)
                .apply(springSecurity())
                .build();
       // ...
       }

    @DisplayName("POST - /stuffs")
    @Nested
    class saveStuff{

        @DisplayName("Return 2xx")
        @Nested
        class Return2xx{

           // some test methods

        @DisplayName("Return 4xx")
        @Nested
        class Return4xx{

          // some tests methods

    }

    @DisplayName("GET - /stuffs/{stuffId}")
    @Nested
    class findStuffById{

        @DisplayName("Return 2xx")
        @Nested
        class Return2xx{

           // some test methods

        @DisplayName("Return 4xx")
        @Nested
        class Return4xx{

          // some tests methods

    }
}
```

As you can see I want to make the class more readable by spliting it in nested classes by Enpoints and for each Endpoint there are nested classes to split by Http response status.

I tried to use `@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_CLASS)` at multiple level and it doesn't clean the Spring Context before each class, The result is the same if I put             `@DirtiesContext(methodMode = DirtiesContext.MethodMode.BEFORE_METHOD)` on each methods.

My goals are to clean the Spring Context before each methods of class `SaveStuff` and clean the context only once at the begin of the class `findStuffById`

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: The problem is more fundamental: SpringExtension does not support nested tests. If you want to use them you have to duplicate all spring testing related annotations in each nested test class.

Comment: @johanneslink Thanks for your response. I tried to put annotations on each nested classes and my conclusion is :
- Dirty ><
- It doesn't seems to works very well in some cases.
In conclusion, I'll make it the old way, by creating a testing class per endpoint ;)

Answer (score 2):

Spring did not provide support for inheriting test configuration from enclosing classes for a JUnit Jupiter `@Nested` test class until Spring Framework 5.3.

For details, see the [`@Nested` test class configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-junit-jupiter-nested-test-configuration) section of the Spring reference manual.

Answer (score 1):

For your information, I faced the same issue while using SpringBoot 2.3, and the problem was fixed with SpringBoot 2.4. Sadly, I didn't find anything to make it work for the version 2.3.