# Async RestController endpoints :: Async result for handler was not set during the specified timeToWait=0

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, asynchronous, spring-mvc-test

We have endpoints of the form:

```java
@GetMapping("/myurl")
public Callable<String> getARandomString(@RequestParam int a) {
```

The application is configured with just one thread (that's why we use `Callable`s to handle this). However, in order to create the tests for this, we do the setup as follows:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {MyApplication.class, MyController.class})
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class MyControllerTest {

    @MockBean
    private MyService myService;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void before() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac)
                .build();

        when(myServices.isOk()).thenReturn(true);
    }

    @Test
    public void given_when_then() throws Exception {

        MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(get("/myurl")
                .param("a", 1))
                .andExpect(request().asyncStarted())
                .andReturn();

        mvcResult.getAsyncResult();

        mockMvc
                .perform(asyncDispatch(mvcResult))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
```

1 test at the time works perfect. On the contrary, when having more **than 1 test** an exception as the following is thrown:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Async result for handler [public java.util.concurrent.Callable<String> com.antmordel.MyController. getARandomString(int)] was not set during the specified timeToWait=0
```

I reckon that it is something about the timeouts. Have anybody had this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I had the exactly same problem. 01 test = OK, multiple tests in 01 run = FAIL.

Fixed by telling the TestRunner to consider that the current test makes the context "dirty".

Add
`@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)` to your test class

See this question [Reload Spring application context after every test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13288029/reload-spring-application-context-after-every-test)